# How to resolve, when importing the package getting unable to resolve class?

Tags: selenium

I am using the below code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

But it is returning..

```
23:08:25,789 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [No match found], see error log for details
23:08:25,791 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [startup failed:
Script2.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.openqa.selenium.By
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import org.openqa.selenium.By
   ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class org.openqa.selenium.By
 @ line 1, column 1.
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1240)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$8.call(CompilationUnit.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:839)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:544)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:493)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:770)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:761)
        at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148)
        at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93)
        at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What's your call to java.exe look like? Seems like you're probably missing the Selenium classes in your Java classpath.

Comment: I've not used Selenium in a while and I'm not familiar with Groovy (which it looks like you're using). I know Groovy is built on Java though and that you're going to need to add the Selenium JAR files to your Java classpath in order to use any of the Selenium functions. This link may help: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running (section titled "Adding things to the classpath")

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the libraries. To add those :

```
@Grapes([
        @Grab("org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2"),
        @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.42.2"),
        @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.42.2")
])
```

Put these above lines at the top of your script.

And after that put the import statements that will use the libraries which will be downloaded to your system first and stored in cache for next time retrievals.

Now Run your script. First time you run your script, it will take some time to Compile as it downloads the libraries to your system and stores in cache.
But from second time onwards, it won't take much time.